# Return Friday if day is weekend (Saturday-Sunday) in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql

I am storing history data as a date type (2019-10-10) in SQL Server. I would like to check and return to Friday if day is Saturday or Sunday.

There is no data at the weekend. That is why I want to get Friday's data if it's weekend.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`( @@DateFirst + DatePart( weekday, SampleDate ) - 1 ) % 7 + 1` will always return an integer from `1` to `7` with `1` corresponding to Sunday regardless of the setting of `DateFirst` or `Language`.

You can use the following code to push weekend dates back to the prior Friday:

```
-- Get the current date (without time).
declare @Today as Date = GetDate();
-- Move Saturday or Sunday dates back to the prior Friday.
select @Today as Today,
  case ( @@DateFirst + DatePart( weekday, @Today ) - 1 ) % 7 + 1
    when 1 then DateAdd( day, -2, @Today ) -- Sunday.
    when 7 then DateAdd( day, -1, @Today ) -- Saturday.
    else @Today end as ReportDate;
```

Comment: This is the most robust solution as it accounts for the DATEFIRST setting.

Answer (score 2):

The safest method is probably to use `format()` for the day of the week:

```
select (case format(col, 'ddd', 'en-us')
           when 'Sat' then dateadd(day, -1, col)
           when 'Sun' then dateadd(day, -2, col)
           else col
        end)
```

Because format takes a culture argument, this works regardless of settings that might affect the date format or language returned by `datename()`.

Answer (score 1):

One option is to use `Choose()` in concert with `DateAdd()`
**Example**

**Example**

```
Declare @YourTable table (DateCol date)
Insert Into @YourTable values
 ('2019-10-14')
,('2019-10-15')
,('2019-10-16')
,('2019-10-17')
,('2019-10-18')
,('2019-10-19')
,('2019-10-20')

Select DateCol
      ,ActDay  = datename(WEEKDAY,DateCol)
      ,AdjDay  = dateadd(DAY,choose(DatePart(WEEKDAY,DateCol),-2,0,0,0,0,0,-1),DateCol)
 From  @YourTable
```

**Returns**

```
DateCol     ActDay      AdjDay
2019-10-14  Monday      2019-10-14
2019-10-15  Tuesday     2019-10-15
2019-10-16  Wednesday   2019-10-16
2019-10-17  Thursday    2019-10-17
2019-10-18  Friday      2019-10-18
2019-10-19  Saturday    2019-10-18  << Friday's Date
2019-10-20  Sunday      2019-10-18  << Friday's Date
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps:

Create table for test:

```
create table HistorySave(Datum date);
```

Insert some test values:

```
Insert into HistorySave values (CONVERT(DATETIME, '2012-06-05', 102));
Insert into HistorySave values (CONVERT(DATETIME, '2012-06-04', 102));
Insert into HistorySave values (CONVERT(DATETIME, '2012-06-03', 102));
Insert into HistorySave values (CONVERT(DATETIME, '2012-06-09', 102));
```

Check what are the days in the inserted data

```
SELECT DATENAME(DW, CONVERT(DATETIME, DATUM, 102)) FROM HistorySave;
```

Check the data before update:

```
select * from HistorySave;
```

Update statement:

```
UPDATE HistorySave  
SET Datum = 
    CASE  
        WHEN DATENAME(DW, CONVERT(DATETIME, Datum, 102)) = 'Saturday' 
            THEN (CONVERT(DATETIME, Datum, 102) -1)
        WHEN DATENAME(DW, CONVERT(DATETIME, Datum, 102)) = 'Sunday' 
            THEN (CONVERT(DATETIME, Datum, 102) -2)
        ELSE 
            DATUM
    END
```

Check the data after update:

```
select * from HistorySave;
```

Demo:

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=358aaefe516da8dd96e1da73ce4d5f38

Answer (score 0):

You need an update  as below

```
        Update table set column=(select 
          column
         From table where to_char(date, 
         'Day') ='FRI') where to_char(date, 
         'Day') LIKE 'S%' ;
```

Comment: to_char? not in tsql.

Answer (score 0):

for specific date use this command

```
DATENAME(dw,CAST(YourSpecificDate AS DATE))
```

so you can check your date as like as this command :

```
select 
 case when DATENAME(dw,CAST(YourSpecificDate AS DATE)) in
 ('Saturday','Sunday') then 'Friday' else DATENAME(dw,CAST('' AS DATE)) end
```

Answer (score -1):

Days are equals to the numbers in sql server:

```
7 -> Sunday
1 -> Monday
2 -> Tuesday
3 -> Wednesday
4 -> Thursday
5 -> Friday
6 -> Saturday
```

`DATEPART(DW, GETDATE())` gives you current day as a number.

Use it in IF AND ELSE in ms sql server.

FOR EXAMPLE:

If day is Saturday(6) use minus 1 to get friday.

```
IF(DATEPART(DW, GETDATE()) = 6)
SELECT * FROM table WHERE date=dateadd(day, -1, cast(GETDATE() as date))
```

Comment: *"Here days are equals to numbers in sql server:"* That totally depends on your language. [DB<>Fiddlle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=f18a30648db71712ef88f0cd8767c1d1). Note, however, that *none* return `0` for today, your statement of `0 -> Sunday` is wrong on all counts I'm afraid.

Comment: it's my bad. i have tried and updated the solution. it is working for me. I have notice about language changes. regards.